# Primary composite key is not unique on both columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two identity columns (id and tenant_id) but I'm having a hard time enforcing data integrity when I perform an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

I have two requirements.

1. `id` column must always be unique
2. the combination of `id` and `tenant_id` should always be unique

**Schema**

```
|id        |int     |AUTO_INCREMENT |PRIMARY
|tenant_id |int     |               |PRIMARY
|name      |varchar |
```

**Data**

```
|id    |tenant_id  |name
------------------------------
|1     |2          |Some name
|2     |1          |Other name
|3     |2          |Another name
```

When I define a Composite Primary key between `id` and `tenant_id` and run an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` the id column allows inserting of the duplicate ID.

So I end up with

```
|id    |tenant_id  |name
------------------------------
|1     |1          |NEW DATA
|1     |2          |Some name
|2     |1          |Other name
|3     |2          |Another name
```

I've tried a large number of combinations with primary and unique index's but I cant get the data to obey the auto increment and primary key on the column (so in the above example the 'new data' should have taken on a new ID of 4).

Comment: Why do you have a composite PK if one of your fields MUST be unique?

Comment: Its a good question, I haven't found a way to make the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE function correctly if I don't specify a composite primary key or a unique aggregate index on the id and tenant_id columns

Answer (score 0):

Then only the first requirement actually matters. If the first column is always different (unique), then the combination with the 2nd column can only be unique, too.